# set width in flutter elevatedbutton

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how can i set width in flutter elevatedbutton, this is my code, thank you

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),                    
                side: BorderSide()
            )
        )
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Baca",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wrap it inside a `Container`, so the child also get the size of parent.

```
Container(
      width: 400,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide()))),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text(
          "Baca",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below answer for **ElevatedButton** width and height :

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Ok"),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        //change width and height on your need width = 200 and height = 50
    minimumSize: Size(200, 50),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a `SizedBox` like this:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          side: BorderSide()
        )
      )
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text(
      "Baca",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
);
```